# MVC Data passage from Javascript Function with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that open a confirmation modal created with bootstrap.

When the modal is confirmed i execute a Javascript function with the data passed from the first button.

This is the button that open the modal:

```
<input class='btn btn-info btnChiusura' type='button' value='Close Day' data-corriere="Bartolini" data-magazzino="@item.NomeMagazzino" data-committente="@ViewBag.comm" />
```

This is the code for click on each btnChiusura of my page:

```
 $('.btnChiusura').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    _self = $(this);
    var corriere = _self.data('corriere');
    var magazzino = _self.data('magazzino');
    var committente = _self.data('committente');
    $("#myModalLabel").text("Close day " + _self.data('corriere') + " " + _self.data('magazzino'));
    $("#myModaBody").text("Conferm close day for " +_self.data('corriere') + " " + _self.data('magazzino')+"?");
    $("#myModalClick").attr("onclick", "Close(" + _self + ");");
    $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

I try to call this function:

```
function ChiusuraGiornata(el) {
alert(el.data('corriere'));};
```

But i have this error on console:

> Unexpected identifier

How can i pass _self data to another javascript funtion?
Thanks to all

Comment: `$('.btnChiusura').data('corriere')` ?

Comment: What is `el` when you are calling `ChiusuraGiornata` method ?

Comment: How are you calling `ChiusuraGiornata` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code you are reading the data attribute of the clicked button and using that to set the title and body content of the modal dialog. If you want to access that later using the `data` attribute again when the button in modal is clicked. You need to set those same values to some elements's data attribute.

You can set those to the "save"/"delete" button which is in the modal so that you can access it when user click on one  of them.

Assuming your modal footer has these 2 buttons.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-save" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Now, before firing the modal, find the button with id "btn-save" and set it's data attribute.

```
$('.btnChiusura').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    _self = $(this);
    var corriere = _self.data('corriere');
    var magazzino = _self.data('magazzino');
    var committente = _self.data('committente');
    $("#myModalLabel").text("Close day " + _self.data('corriere') +
                                     " " + _self.data('magazzino'));
    $("#myModaBody").text("Conferm close day for " + _self.data('corriere') + " " 
                                                   + _self.data('magazzino') + "?");
    $("#myModalClick").attr("onclick", "Close(" + _self + ");");

    // Set the attributes to the button in modal.
    $("#btn-save").attr("data-magazzino", magazzino).attr("data-corriere", corriere);

    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Now when the button is clicked,you can read it's `data("magazzino")` to get the value you set.

```
$(document).on("click","#btn-save",function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr("data-corriere"));
    alert($(this).attr("data-magazzino"));

});
```